# How to Add minute to EventdateTime and convert to DateTime

Tags: java, android, time, google-calendar-api, date

I am using Google API, and I need to add minutes to an EventDateTime and send it back in DateTime format.

```
req.setTimeMin(start.getDateTime());
```

start is an EventDateTime and I can convert it to Datetime with getDateTime.

But I cant do `DateTime end = start.getDateTime().plusMinutes(30)`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.html) there is no method `plusMinutes()` defined on `DateTime`.

Comment: ho yeah, i am completly stupid, i confuse with : http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the value in milliseconds:

```
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;

...

DateTime end = new DateTime(start.getDateTime().getValue() + 30L * 60L * 1000L);
```

Comment: ho yeah!! You save my day for hanging myself! thank you

Comment: @RaphaelObadia Glad it helped.